# Calculating the sum of integers in an array

Tags: c, arrays

I don't know if I'm just being a total fool, most likely I am, it's been a long day, but this isn't working as I want it to, and, well, I don't see why.

It should be able to have 11 numbers entered, a new number on each line, add them to the array, then total them, yet it's just not working. It's not stopping to exit the loop, even though I am incrementing i.

Any ideas?

```
int main(void) {
 int array[10];
 int i;
 int sum = 0;
  for ( i = 0; i < 11; i++){
   scanf("%d", &array[i]);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
   sum += array[i];
  }
printf("%d", sum);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Your array only has space for 10 elements.

Comment: If you declare an array of ten integers, the valid indexes are from 0 to 9; in your code you also use array[10] that is the 11th element of an array of ten. I don't know C at all but I guess it can be an issue. My 2 cents

Comment: It's "bitten" many of us at one time or another, not always when we were rank beginners.  Especially confusing if you move back and forth between a C-based language and one of the (few) 1-origin-array languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 10 elements in the array, numbered 0 - 9. You are overflowing the buffer, so all bets are off. This is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Ah jees, I knew it was somthing stupid, I thought 10 element array meant 0 to 10, thus 11 elements.. Just me being foolish

Answer (score 3):

You can't add eleven entries to a ten-element array.

Comment: But the array starts from 0 I thought, and 0 through to 10, is 11 elements.

Comment: @user1048116 it isn't 0-10 though, there are 10 elements total, so starting at 0 that is 0 through 9

Answer (score 3):

My guess is buffer over-run since the for-loop reads in 11 numbers and the 11th number gets stored outside the array, probably overwriting i.

Try changing the 11 to a 10 in the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You're storing eleven numbers into an array of size 10. Thus you're storing the last element out of bounds, which invokes undefined behavior.

The reason that this undefined behavior manifests itself as an infinite loop in your case is probably that `i` is stored after `array` in memory on your system and when you write a number into `array[10]` (which is out of bounds, as I said), you're overwriting `i`. So if you entered a number smaller than 11 this will cause the loop to continue and ask for input once more.

Answer (score 1):

If an array is a[10], then every array starts from its index number 0, so here it will have 10 elements; given that their positions will start from 0 to 9, counting gives 10 elements.

You can try this:

```
main()         
{        
    int a[10], i, n, sum=0;    

    printf("enter no. of elements");
    scanf("%d",&n); 
    printf("enter the elements");   

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)    
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);

    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        sum=sum+a[i];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("\n a[%d] = %d", i, a[i]);

    printf("\n sum = %d",sum);
    getch();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have problems with your array declaration. You are defining an array of size 10 `array[10]` and saying the program to calculate the sum of **11** elements which is resulting in memory overflows.

To correct the program just increase size of the array as `array[11]`.  Also if you wish you can check the [recursive approach to find sum of array elements](http://www.codeforwin.in/2016/03/c-program-to-print-elements-of-array-using-recursion.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void main() {
 int array[10];
 int i;
 int sum = 0;

  for ( i = 0; i < 11; i++){
   scanf("%d", &array[i]);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
   sum = sum + array[i] ;
  }
printf("%d", sum);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    //this the sum of integers in an array
    int array[] = { 22,2,2,1,5,4,5,7,9,54,4,5,4 },x,sum=0;
    int cout_elements = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);
    for (x = 0; x < cout_elements; x++) {
        
        sum += array[x];

    }
    printf("%d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Useful but will not work for the task in this specific question. Elements of the array had to be keyed in (entered) not predefined.

Answer (score -1):

```
int main()
{
    int a[10];
    int i,j;
    int x=0;
    printf("Enter no of arrays:");
    scanf("%d",&j);
    printf("Enter nos:");
    for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for (i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
        x=x+a[i];
    }
    printf("Sum of Array=%d",x);
    return 0;
}
```