# How to sum all values in a same variable?

Tags: c, cs50

I am working on an assignment but the code is doing some weird stuff. It is my 7th day "programming", so it might be just an obvious mistake, which I simply cannot see.

I want the program to sum all values stored in a same variable. I tried to replicate some code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42166389, but it did not work as expected.

**So**, given a set of values *-let's say 012345-*, the program should take every other number *-4, 2, and 0-*, and sum them *-giving back "6"-*. And, although it does identify the digits, it does not sum them... at least properly.
*I do not understand why, but it gives back 48*.

I have tried different inputs, and while identifying the digits properly, in all cases the sum was wrong.

I would really appreciate any help.
Oh, and here is my code!:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char c;
    string number;
    int length, i, sum = 0;

    printf("Type card number: ");
    number = get_string();

    printf("Tell us how many characters long was your number: ");
    length = get_int();

    for (i = 1; i <= length / 2; i++) {
        c = number[(strlen(number) - i * 2)];
        sum = c;
        printf("%c %i %s\n", c, sum, number);
    }
}
```

Some examples:

For input `012345` and `length=6`, the output is:

```
4 52 012345
2 50 012345
0 48 012345
```

For input `9876543210` and `length=10`, the output is:

```
1 49 9876543210
3 51 9876543210
5 53 9876543210
7 55 9876543210
9 57 9876543210
```

And, just to summarize, what I want is a way of summing all the values in a same variable.

Comment: The digits are encoded as [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters), so `'0'` is 48,  `'1'` is 49, etc.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the `atoi` function. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 sum = c;
```

You are assigning ASCII value to sum.You should get the corresponding number and also add it to sum, not just assign.

```
 4 52 012345  //52 is ASCII value of 4
 2 50 012345  //50 is ASCII value of 2
 0 48 012345  //48 is ASCII value of 0
```

Try this,

```
 sum+=c-'0';
```

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the solution!

Now, I don't know how did I write it in ASCII, could you explain me where did that happen? 
I understand the change from *sum=c* to *sum+=c*; but -and finally- how does *-'0'* convert ASCII to... number?

Again, thank you VERY much!

Comment: `'0'` means 48(ASCII of 0) so `52-48=4`.If it worked for you,please accept this as answer.

Comment: It did. Thank you very much!