# Calculating sum of array

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

int numOfMeal, items[50];//, sum;

 printf("Enter number of meals/snacks: ");
 scanf("%d",&numOfMeal);

 for(int i=1; i<=numOfMeal;i++)
 {
  printf("Enter kilojoules for item %d: ", i);
  scanf("%d", &items[numOfMeal]);

  }
  printf("Your total kilojoules are: %d", items[numOfMeal]);




 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```

any ideas on how to calculate the sum of arrays, when i run this program it only displays the last kilojoule entered..

Comment: your code merely placed the input into the array, there is no summation of the values.

Comment: You know how to add variables in C? Did you go to the lectures ;-)

Comment: Array indexes start at 0, not at 1.

Comment: Hint: among other problems: there is a very obvious problem here `scanf("%d", &items[numOfMeal]);`

Comment: - into the (non-existent) element beyond the last element in the array, that is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating the sum of integers in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300888/calculating-the-sum-of-integers-in-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

1.

You should run the loop from 0 to `numOfMeal`-1 because array indexing starts from the 0, not 1. If you are accessing the nth element that is a segmentation fault.

2.

The second problem in your code is that you are not taking the input values in the array. Your loop is, again and again, overwriting the `items[numOfMeal]` which is the last element in your array.

Write your code as below:

```
 int numOfMeal, items[50],sum=0;

 printf("Enter number of meals/snacks: ");
 scanf("%d",&numOfMeal);

 for(int i=0; i<numOfMeal;i++) // run loop from 0 to numOfMeal-1
 {
      printf("Enter kilojoules for item %d: ", i);
      scanf("%d", &items[i]); // take the input at ith position in the array 
      sum+=items[i];  // sum them

 }
  printf("Your total kilojoules are: %d", sum);  // print the final result
```

The short code for this can be

```
 int numOfMeal, item, sum=0;
 scanf("%d",&numOfMeal);
 for(int i=0; i<numOfMeal;i++){
      scanf("%d", &item);
      sum+=item;
 }
 printf("Your total kilojoules are: %d", sum);
```

In this code I am not storing the value in the array, just saving it temporarily in the variable and add it to sum variable.

Comment: without some explanation this answer might be correct but is not really helpful.

Comment: Actually, this is very basic program anyone can understand it just by reading and dry run. Hardly take a minute  :)

Comment: Well then the question would not have been asked if it was that easy for OP.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please check it, if now it is holding the explanation.

Comment: This is a very good edit. A little tip, You can mark variables/refrences to the code by embracing it in ` then it looks like `this`.

Answer (score 0):

1) change your `for` loop. indexes of array start at 0. change `i = 1` to `i = 0` and `i <= numOfMeal` to `i < numOfMeal`

2) you have to calculate sum of array elements in loop

```
...
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numOfMeal; i++)
{
    ...
    result += items[i];
}
printf("Your total kilojoules are: %d", result);
...
```